# React Native bottom sheet opens when TextInput has autofocus prop

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using [react-native-bottom-sheet](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/) for choosing a category and when the Amount input has the `autofocus` property the bottom sheet appears on the screen. And it looks like this

[image: Bug screenshot]

The bottom sheet appears behind the keyboard, and it doesn't follow the snap point I want, it should be at the middle of the screen but it is always slightly above the keyboard. This doesn't happen all the time, like 2/5 tries, and only when I open this screen for the first time. The sheet should only open when I tap on the category and it should be hidden when entering the screen.
I tried to use some variable `render` to check if the bottom sheet even needs to render or not, so  I don't render it at all but then I could see it just flicker for a second.

This is my bottom sheet component. Because I want to create a reusable component I used ref to pass the function for opening the bottom sheet to the parent.

```
const TransactionBottomSheet: React.ForwardRefRenderFunction<refProps, Props> = (props, ref) => {
  const { onSelect } = props;
  const sheetRef = useRef<BottomSheet>(null);
  const [data, setData] = useState<Transaction[]>(categoriesData);
  const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState<Category | null>(null);

  const openSheet = useCallback(() => {
    sheetRef.current?.expand();
  }, []);
  const closeSheet = useCallback(() => {
    sheetRef.current?.close();
  }, []);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    openSheet: () => openSheet(),
  }));

  const setTypeData = (id: number) => {
    const types = transactionCategories[id].types ?? [];
    setData(Object.values(types));
  };

  const clearCategory = () => {
    setData(categoriesData);
    setSelectedCategory(null);
  };

  const onRowPress = (item: Transaction | Category) => {
    if (!selectedCategory) {
      setTypeData(item.id);
      setSelectedCategory(item as Category);
    } else {
      onSelect(selectedCategory, item);
      closeSheet();
    }
  };

  const onClose = () => {
    setData(categoriesData);
    setSelectedCategory(null);
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item }: { item: Transaction | Category }) => (
    <TransactionRowSelect item={item} hideIcon={!!selectedCategory} onPress={onRowPress} />
  );

  const renderBackdrop = useCallback(
    (props) => <BottomSheetBackdrop {...props} disappearsOnIndex={-1} appearsOnIndex={0} />,
    []
  );

  return (
    <BottomSheet
      ref={sheetRef}
      snapPoints={snapPoints}
      enablePanDownToClose
      index={-1}
      onClose={onClose}
      backdropComponent={renderBackdrop}
      handleStyle={styles.handle}
    >
      <Label style={styles.title}>{"Pick category"}</Label>
      {!!selectedCategory && (
        <>
          <TransactionRowSelect item={selectedCategory} onPress={clearCategory} />
          <Separator />
        </>
      )}
      <BottomSheetFlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item) => `${item.id}`}
        renderItem={renderItem}
      />
    </BottomSheet>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  title: {
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    paddingBottom: 10,
    backgroundColor: colors.grey3,
  },
  handle: {
    backgroundColor: colors.grey3,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
    borderTopRightRadius: 10,
  },
});

export default React.forwardRef(TransactionBottomSheet);
```

And this is Add transaction screen

```
const TransactionForm: React.FC<Props> = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const sheetRef = useRef<TransactionBottomSheetType>(null);
  const [category, setCategory] = useState<Category | null>(null);
  const [type, setType] = useState<Transaction | null>(null);
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");

  const [tryCreateNewTransaction, { isLoading }] = useCreateNewTransactionMutation();
  const onAdd = async () => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    try {
      if (type && category) {
        await tryCreateNewTransaction({
          amount: Number(amount),
          description,
          date: formatIsoDate(date),
          user_id: 1,
          type_id: type.id,
          category_id: category.id,
        }).unwrap();
        navigation.goBack();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert("An error occurred while adding transaction", "Please try again");
    }
  };

  const onSelectCategory = (category: Category, type: Transaction) => {
    setCategory(category);
    setType(type);
  };

  const setCategoryText = () => {
    if (!category && !type) {
      return "";
    }
    return `${category?.label}, ${type?.label}`;
  };

  const openSheet = () => {
    if (sheetRef?.current) {
      Keyboard.dismiss();
      sheetRef?.current?.openSheet();
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <DatePickerInput date={date} maximumDate={new Date()} onDateSelect={setDate} />
      // This is just TextInput component with some custom style, here is the autofocus props
      <LabelInput
        value={amount}
        placeholder='Amount'
        onChangeText={setAmount}
        keyboardType='decimal-pad'
        style={styles.marginTop}
        icon={<FontAwesome5 name='coins' size={24} color={colors.greenMint} />}
        autoFocus
      />
      {/* <InputErrorLabel text={errors.amount} isVisible={!!errors.amount} /> */}
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={openSheet}>
        <LabelInput
          value={setCategoryText()}
          icon={<MaterialIcons name='category' size={24} color={colors.greenMint} />}
          disabled
          placeholder='Category'
          style={styles.marginTop}
          inputStyle={styles.category}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TextBox
        placeholder='Transaction comment'
        style={styles.marginTop}
        numberOfLines={6}
        maxLength={300}
        value={description}
        onChangeText={setDescription}
      />
      <CustomButton title='Submit' onPress={onAdd} style={styles.marginTop} />
      <AppActivityIndicator isLoading={isLoading} />
      <TransactionBottomSheet ref={sheetRef} onSelect={onSelectCategory} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default TransactionForm;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    paddingTop: 20,
  },
  marginTop: {
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  category: {
    color: colors.black,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a fix for the problem, it looks like it had to do with the keyboard and expo. I noticed that when the keyboard is shown or dismissed there is a white background showing behind it for a split second. I fixed this by adding this to `app.json`

```
 "android": {
      "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan"
    },
```

This fixed problem with the keyboard and bottom sheet also. Didn't see it appear anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the keyboard `show/hide` and do whatever you want with the bottom sheet.
for example, here I'm changing the snapping point of the bottom sheet.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {

    let keyboardHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', () => {
      if (isBottomSheetOpen.current) {
        bottomSheetRef.current?.snapToIndex(0);
      }
    });

    let keyboardShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', () => {
      if (isBottomSheetOpen.current) {
        bottomSheetRef.current?.snapToIndex(1);
      }
    });

    return () => {
      keyboardHideListener.remove();
      keyboardShowListener.remove();
    };

  }, []);
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: okay, here you are